# How do I create a custom map view pin with a dynamic element?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I am trying to create a custom pin which has a label in the center of the pin which will change with every pin. The label will just be the pin number, so if I have 8 pins each pin will have a number in the center i.e. 1st pin will have 1, 2nd pin will have 2, etc. The issue is that the regular pin appears, not the custom pin.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapView.delegate = self
    loadPins()
}

func loadPins() {
        let annotation = CustomPin()
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 30.2531419, longitude: -97.78785789999999)
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }


class AnView: UIView {


    @IBOutlet weak var countLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pinImage: UIImageView!


    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        //Draw function
    }

}

class CustomPin: MKPointAnnotation {
    var pin = AnView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))

}
```

Comment: Can we see your [`mapView(viewFor:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/1452045-mapview)? That dictates how the annotation view is generated.

Comment: See [Maps and Location Programming Guide: Defining a Custom Annotation View](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW46)

Answer (score 0):

The annotation (your `CustomPin`) gets the latitude/longitude values.

The annotation view (which your code doesn't show) gets the label or image you want to show on the map.

Since the [Maps and Location Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW46) from the comments gives all of its examples in Objective-C, you might want to also look at this RayWenderlich.com tutorial for Swift help:
[MapKit Tutorial: Getting Started](https://www.raywenderlich.com/90971/introduction-mapkit-swift-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

You can draw the number over the map pin image. Just create a function (or extension) to add text over the image like this:

```
func addTextOverImage(_ text: String, overImage image: UIImage) -> UIImage {

    //set scale and context
    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, false, scale)

    image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: image.size))

    //set font face, size and color
    let textColor = UIColor.black
    let textFont = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)

    //define the text attributes
    let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraph.alignment = .center

    let textFontAttributes = [
        NSFontAttributeName: textFont,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor,
        NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraph
        ] as [String : Any]

    //set the text position (in the image rect)
    let textPoint=CGPoint.init(x: 0.0, y: image.size.height/2)
    //create the rect to draw the text
    let rect = CGRect(origin: textPoint, size: image.size)
    //draw the text over the image, in the rect just defined
    text.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    //return image with text
    return newImage!
}
```

You may need to adjust the `textPoint` in the function to get the text positioned where you want it to be.